# JavaFX show ImageView from other class array

Tags: java, javafx

there i have made Minimal Code base as passible, hope it helps as example u can use random PNG image files as you want in Class 2 in constructor BufferedImage.getSubImage is getting all needed images from only 1 file and adding every single BufferedImage converted to ImageView giving it to every array up to 32 :)

Class 1:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur;
import javafx.scene.effect.Glow;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application{
private GameMenu gameMenu;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // nastavenie pozadia

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(1600,900);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false); // resize okna = false
    primaryStage.show(); // kebyze to nemame mame hnusne biele okraje xD

    this.gameMenu = new GameMenu();
    this.gameMenu.setVisible(true);

    root.getChildren().addAll(this.gameMenu);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


} // End start

private class GameMenu extends Parent {
    public GameMenu() throws Exception {
        BalikKariet m = new BalikKariet();
        VBox menu0 = new VBox(15);
        menu0.setTranslateX(650);
        menu0.setTranslateY(300);

        GameMenuCSS btn1 = new GameMenuCSS("Random Text");
        btn1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            getChildren().addAll(m.zoberKartu().getObrazok());
        });

        menu0.getChildren().addAll(btn1);
        getChildren().addAll(menu0);
    } // End Const.



} // End GameMenu

public static class GameMenuCSS extends StackPane {
    private Text text;

    public GameMenuCSS(String text) {
        this.text = new Text(text);
        this.text.setFont(this.text.getFont().font(20));
        this.text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(250,30);
        bg.setOpacity(0.6);
        bg.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(3.5);
        bg.setEffect(blur);

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setRotate(-0.5);
        getChildren().addAll(bg, this.text);

        setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            bg.setTranslateX(10);
            this.text.setTranslateX(10);
            bg.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            this.text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        });

        setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            bg.setTranslateX(0);
            this.text.setTranslateX(0);
            bg.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            this.text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        });

        DropShadow drop = new DropShadow(50, Color.WHITE);
        drop.setInput(new Glow());

        setOnMousePressed(event -> setEffect(drop));
        setOnMouseReleased(event -> setEffect(null));

    } // koniec konstruktora
} // koniec Triedy MenuPolosky



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
}
```

Class 2 :

```
package com.sayky.test;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BalikKariet {
private Karta[] balik;
private int dalsiaKarta; // index nasledujucej karty
private ImageView imgViwVsetkyKarty;
private ImageView tempImageViewObrazokKarty;

public BalikKariet() throws IOException {
    int[] hodnota = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    String[] typKariet = {"7","8","9","10","Dolek","Horek","Kral","Eso"};
    String[] farbay = {"Zelen","Cervem","Gula","Zalud"};

    balik = new Karta[32];
    dalsiaKarta = 0;

    final int sirka = 74;
    final int vyska = 120;
    final int riadky = 4;
    final int stlpec = 8;

    BufferedImage vssetkyKartyObrazok = ImageIO.read(new     File("res/img/vsetkyKarty.png"));
    Image imgVsetkyKarty = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(vssetkyKartyObrazok, null);
    imgViwVsetkyKarty = new ImageView(imgVsetkyKarty);
    BufferedImage tempObrazokKarty;


    for (int farba = 0; farba < 4 ; farba++){
        for (int typKarty = 0; typKarty < 8; typKarty++){
            //ukaz obrazok
            tempObrazokKarty = vssetkyKartyObrazok.getSubimage(
                    typKarty*sirka,     // zaciatok x suradnic
                    farba*vyska,        // zaciatok y sura dnic
                    sirka,              // sirka
                    vyska);             // vyska
            balik[(typKarty + (farba*8))] = new Karta(
                    farbay[farba],      // zavola Farby Array aby nadobudla meno Farba
                    typKariet[typKarty],
                    typKarty+7,         // pozicia 0+7 je 7 zacina na hodnote prvej karty
                    tempImageViewObrazokKarty);
            Image tempImgObrazokKarty = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempObrazokKarty, null);
            tempImageViewObrazokKarty = new ImageView(tempImgObrazokKarty);
        }
    }

} // koniec konstruktora

public Karta zoberKartu(){
    if ( dalsiaKarta< balik.length) {
        return balik[dalsiaKarta++];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

} // koniec classy

Class 3 :

```
package com.sayky.test;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Karta {
private String typkarty; // cislo karty
private String farba; // telo
private int hodnota; // hodnota karty
private ImageView kartaObrazok;
/**
 *  Konstruktor pre PexesovaKarta triedu bude obsahovat toto ( pre lepsiu orientaciu )
 * @param farba -suit- "Zelen" "Cerven" "Gula" "Zalud"
 * @param typkarty -face- = 7, 8, 9, 10, Dolek, Horek, Kral, Eso;
 * @param hodnota = 7, 8, 9, 10, 11-dolek, 12-horek, 13-kral, 14-eso;
 */
public Karta(String farba, String typkarty, int hodnota, ImageView kartaObrazok) {
    // nastavenie hodnot lokalnich premien do globalnich
    this.farba = farba;
    this.typkarty = typkarty;
    this.hodnota = hodnota;
}
public String toString(){
    return typkarty + " " + farba;
}

public int getHodnotaKarty(){
    return hodnota;
}
public Karta getKarta() {
    return this;
}
public ImageView getObrazok() {
    return kartaObrazok;
}
}
```

Comment: When you say it crashes, do you get an error with it? If so, please share.

Comment: Also, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) what be greatly helpful.

Comment: @Jonah

Error :'Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = GameMenuDemo$GameMenu@66820790'

at com.sayky.sedma.GameMenuDemo$GameMenu.lambda$new$15(GameMenuDemo.java:333) 

this line is  'getChildren().addAll(m.bk.getKartaBalik(0).getObrazok()); '

it doesnt not crash it just show this error and nothing happends

Comment: So you're never instantiating the node you are trying to add.

Comment: @Jonah
any example ? cause i inicialized all i think ( methids m ) methods is class and in constructior i have bk = new BalikKariet()

Comment: What @Jonah is saying is that `getObrazok()` is returning null. No one can tell you why that is unless you create and post a [MCVE]  (though you don't seem to initialize the field in the constructor; is that what you are missing?)

Comment: @Jonah 
here is Minimal code base hope its helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Karta` class never initializes the `kartaObrazok` field, so `getObrazok()` returns null.

Comment: it is in class 2 in for  where i make new karta 32 times and to every single karta[0] , karta[1] ..... it get kartaObrazok = tempImageViewObrazokKarty

also adding this.kartaObrazok = kartaObrazok; to  class 3 doesnt fix it =\

Comment: But that is not the value returned by `getObrazok()`. The value returned by that method is the field `kartaObrazok` defined in the `Karta` class. That field is never assigned a value.

Comment: Also, you only initialize the temporary variable *after* you create the `Karta` instance. So on the first iteration of the loop you will be passing null as the parameter to the `Karta` constructor.

Comment: THX fixed it adding before Balik[] this 2 lines 
Image tempImgObrazokKarty = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempObrazokKarty, null);
                tempImageViewObrazokKarty = new ImageView(tempImgObrazokKarty);

Comment: and is passible biuld .jar file with biuld artifacts ? cause its always close .jar file when i try open it